# Is it bad for deliverability to have send-only email addresses?

Tags: email, email-delivery

For example:

- updates@newsletter.example.com
- david@newsletter.example.com
- mary@newsletter.example.com
- etc.

They would be used only to send some updates and newsletters.

Is it ok if those email addresses are **send-only** (**like noreply**, they cannot receive emails)?

Or that has an impact on the deliverability (i.e. some providers may see that as spam)?

Answer (score 0):

95% of the time this is fine, if *annoying* for customers who might want to make additional inquiries.

Maybe 5% of the time the receiving party will attempt to validate that the address exists and is accepting mail. If the server refuses delivery to that mailbox it will flag it as spam. This is often on what one might term *artisanal* mail servers run by highly opinionated owners who turn on every validation switch they can get their hands on.